# Incorrect favorites count on careers page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, bookmarks

The two job listings I had marked as favorites have expired over the past few weeks, but my favorites count is still two. On the main careers page it says "your favorites (2)", but no jobs are listed.

The count is correct in the sidebar on the job search page and the actual favorites page, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, this should be resolved.